# Wrong output format using Background Subtraction with OpenCV C++/CLI

Tags: c++, opencv, background, picturebox, subtraction

I got a question regarding to `OpenCV 2.3.1` with `C++/CLI`. I take the output of `C++/CLI` and display it into C# `pictureBox`.

When I use Gaussian background subtraction to analyse image, the format of output when converting to `cvMat` is not what I expected. The BG subtraction frame is split & duplicated into 3 sessions. Also, its.`type()` and `channels()` is different from the raw frame

[image: Wrong display]

However, when display frames sequence using `cvShowImage()` (instead of C# picturebox), it shows correctly.

Here is the code for `Background subtraction`

```
void NormalBGSubtraction_Adapter::BackgroundSubtraction(IplImage *proImg, IplImage* &maskImg)
{
    Mat     pImg(proImg);
    Mat     mImg;

    bg.operator()(pImg, mImg);
    erode(mImg, mImg, cv::Mat());
    dilate(mImg, mImg, cv::Mat());

    maskImg = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)mImg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your concerns.
Finally, after some days, I figure it out the reason of errors: Because of the incorrect format produced by background subtraction methods above.

My C# pictureBox expects `RGB`, not `GRAY`. However, after `erode` and `dilate`, it by somehow make the mImg to `GRAY` format.

All I done is just converting back to `RGB`:

```
void NormalBGSubtraction_Adapter::BackgroundSubtraction(IplImage *proImg, IplImage*      &maskImg)
{
    Mat     pImg(proImg);
    Mat     mImg;

    bg.operator()(pImg, mImg);

    /*
    erode and dilate meaning : Removing noise  
    Isolation of individual elements and joining disparate elements in an image.
    Finding of intensity bumps or holes in an image
    */

    erode(mImg, mImg, cv::Mat());
    dilate(mImg, mImg, cv::Mat());

    cvtColor(mImg, mImg, CV_GRAY2RGB);
    maskImg = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)mImg);

}
```

Hope it helps if anyone face with the same situation :)

Cheers,